# c# Program Saying Answer Is Correct Regardless Of Input

Tags: c#, windows, parsing, math, addition

The program always says the answer is correct with any number you input. It outputs it as incorrect when you type a character. I'm not sure why it is doing this. I'm new to C# so go easy!

```
   // Create a Random object to generate random numbers.
    Random randomizer = new Random();

    // for the addition problem. 
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int sum;
    int correct;
    int incorrect;

    private void play_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartTheGame();

    }

    public void StartTheGame()
    {
        num1 = randomizer.Next(11);
        num2 = randomizer.Next(11);
        sum = num1 + num2;
        labelNum1.Text = num1.ToString();
        labelNum2.Text = num2.ToString();
    }

    private void labelNum1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnSub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(txtUserAnswer.Text, out sum))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Correct Answer!", "Correct");
            correct++;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You messed up.", "Incorrect");
            incorrect++;
        }
        txtUserAnswer.Clear();
        txtUserAnswer.Focus();
        StartTheGame();

        if(correct == 5)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Congrats! You defeated the monster.", "Next Level");
        }

        if(incorrect == 3)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You've been defeated. Nerd.", "Loser");
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Please help me! It's for school and this is bothering me!

Comment: What is it supposed to do? The return from int.TryParse is true if the passed string can be successfully parsed to an int.

Comment: sounds like you need to  set breakpoints and start debugging the code also try setting the initialized int's = `0` and check the value of the out variable = to something this is basic coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do here is just to try parse. As long as the input of the `int.TryParse(txtUserAnswer.Text, out sum)` is integer, this condition is always `true`.

```
txtUserAnswer.Text = "1235"; //this result in true
txtUserAnswer.Text = "44"; //this result in true
txtUserAnswer.Text = "999999"; //this result in true
txtUserAnswer.Text = "123bbn"; //this result in false
```

You have to add a checking condition using different variable name than `sum`. Otherwise, your `sum` will be replaced by the input of the user:

```
int guesssum; //declare this
.
.
if (int.TryParse(txtUserAnswer.Text, out guesssum)) //use guesssum here
{
    if (guesssum == sum){
        MessageBox.Show("Correct Answer!", "Correct");
        correct++;
    }
    else {
         //wrong, do something!
    }
}
```

Comment: Good catch, I failed to see he was reusing sum.

Comment: Sorry guys! Thank you so much! <3

Comment: @Ian I don't think he has enough points to accept the answer (I think you have to have at least 15). That's why I gave you the upvote, at least you'll get some points.

Comment: @Kevin Accepting answers does not require any reputation.